# Exotic smooth structures on Lie groups?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, lie-groups, differential-topology, smooth-structures

If a topological group $G$ is also a topological manifold, it is well-known (Hilbert's 5th Probelm) that there is a unique analytic structure making it a Lie group.

However, for a compact Lie group $G$, do we know if the underlying topological manifold supports any other exotic smooth structures (necessarily not a Lie group)?

Even a more specific example: Up to diffeomorphism, we have $SO(8)=SO(7)\times S^7$. If we replace the smooth structure on $S^7$ by an exotic one, do we get an exotic smooth structure on $SO(8)$?

Thank you!

Comment: There are uncountably many different smooth structures on the Lie group $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu, you are right, let me add the compactness

Comment: I don't believe your example. There is a fiber bundle $SO(7) \to SO(8) \to S^7$ but I see no reason to expect that it trivializes.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Think of $S^7$ as unit octonions and $SO(7)$ as rotations preserving the unit octonion, then every element in $SO(8)$ can be uniquely represented as a left multiplication by a unit octonion composed with an element in $SO(7)$. This decomposition trivializes the bundle.

Comment: @Piojo: wouldn't that same argument show that $SO(4) \cong SO(3) \times S^3$? I know both of these spaces admit $S^3 \times S^3$ as a double cover but I was under the impression that they were quotients by nonconjugate actions of $\mathbb{Z}_2$, although maybe that's not true...

Comment: @QiaochuYuan $SO(4)$ is homeomorphic to what you said by the same argument. I believe this is even in Hatcher somewhere, maybe the additional topic on orthogonal groups.

Comment: Huh. Well, I learned something today.

Comment: As Lie group, $SO(4)$ is even a semidirect $SU(2)\rtimes SO(3)$, where the action is induced by conjugation (since $SO(3)=PSU(2)$).

Answer (score 10):

There are two smooth structures on a five-torus, aren't there?

S^7 is the units in the octonions.  Maybe left multiplication furnishes a section of the principal SO(7)-bundle SO(8)-->S^7.

Comment: Thanks! Can you give a reference on smooth structures on five-torus? Do you any thought on the example I mentioned?

Comment: $T^5$ has two PL structures, hence it has two smooth structures. See (Example 3.10 of http://www.indiana.edu/~jfdavis/teaching/m623/dp.pdf)

Answer (score 10):

According to the introduction to the following paper of Farrell and Jones, if $n>4$ and $\Sigma^n$ is any exotic homotopy sphere, then $T^n\#\Sigma^n$ is not diffeomorphic to $T^n$. So lots of higher-dimensional tori have exotic structures. Farrell and Jones cite Section 15A of Wall's book on surgery for this result, but I couldn't pull it easily out of there. In any case, here's the paper reference:

Farrell, F. T.; Jones, L. E.
Examples of expanding endomorphisms on exotic tori. 
Invent. Math. 45 (1978), no. 2, 175–179.