# Exotic structures on compact Lie groups

Tags: differential-topology

Is there a publication reviewing the results on exotic structures on manifolds?
I am not a specialist, but I have a proof of existence of exotic structures on a wide class of compact Lie groups. What is known about the existence/nonexistence of such structures in general? I have only seen results on spheres and some specific low dimensional manifolds.
I would greatly appreciate if you somebody would kindly give me this information.

Comment: You should add "smooth" to "exotic structures".

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of http://mathoverflow.net/questions/225910/exotic-smooth-structures-on-lie-groups . See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/239148/does-every-dimension-n-geq4-admit-a-manifold-with-an-exotic-smooth-structure/239162#239162